# URL Redirect Issue

Tags: redirection, .htaccess, uri

I am using Drupal 7. 
When you type the website url: `www.exampleCountry.com`, it gets redirected to `www.example.com`. Now, I need to change the `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/country/countryName/`.

Will changing this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]
```

in the .htaccess file help?

Can you please help me with the same?

Comment: make any change in .htaccess file, you need to restart server. Try to restart server.

Comment: @NishantP Really? Are you sure about that!! I don't think so. As far as I know,  restart is not required for changes to .htaccess

Comment: Many times whenever I made changes on .htaccess without restart server am not got any reflection. So I just suggest, nothing else.

Comment: The point of .htaccess is that it's parsed per request - restarting the server after changing .htaccess will have no effect

Comment: But will making the above change in the .htaccess file serve my purpose?